# use of twitter apis in android

Tags: java, android

i spent my time mainly as a graphic/web designer. I realize that there is no really beautiful designed twitter client for android. So, I designed the UI myself and its quiet impressive I have to say. The problem is, I never went past the android tutorials on the developers website because Im about to start college and lack the time of continuing to learn all the stuffs of it. I just wanted to know if there is a COMPLETE tutorial on how to build a twitter client for android with what I have right now. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php), a Twitter client library for Java. See also [this-blog](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/1089/) and [follow this tutorial](http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/for-all-my-code-thirsty-friends-twitter.html)